# Android emulator problem related with nested virtualization

Tags: react-native, virtual-machine

I have Windows 10 host machine and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS guest machine on Oracle VM Virtual Box.

I want to practice a react native project in VirtualBox with Android Emulator. But whenever I run the android emulator, I only see a black screen. There were no Google logo or something else, just black screen. Also this message: "Emulator is running using nested virtualization."

I tried everything on internet. I give 9GB Ram and 3 cores of CPU to increase performance, I checked nested VT-x optiom from VMBox, I have 6.1 VirtualBox version. But nothing helped to get rid off black screen.

How can I start the virtual machine emulator on Oracle Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you're trying to attempt is very sound; however, it is a virtualbox issue. While you can run nested virtual environments in Virtualbox on AMD and Intel CPUs, virtualbox has limited the nested environments on intel CPUs down to Gen5 Broadwell and onwards.

So if your CPU is Gen4 like mine right now and still want to run Android Studio to test few things, try going for ARM emulation instead of x86.

[image: Creating a new Virtual Device]

Here is a reference [LINK](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=94724) to the Intel Gen5 supporting nested virtualization.

The above link was referenced in [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/1406281/virtual-box-running-android-studio-virtual-device-needs-vtx) location. Obviously some people out there are more clever than myself. I just had the luxury of landing there.

Now your next question should be: how versatile is this ARM AVD inside a Virtualbox VM? Not so much, slow as a snail. At times I feel I want to kill the apps altogether. In fact I wasn't able to run any android version newer than 4.1.

You will need to try a different virtualization environment, like Hyper-V or KVM.